# Connect Sharepoint with c# via PnPCore

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, pnp-core-sdk

I use method GetWebLoginClientContext to access Sharepoint with MFA.

It was perfect since multiple users will use this program and i didn't want user to write any password/got any credential within code for security sake.

This worked for few days then now i got below screen saying that browser needs now to be updated.
Is there any workarround ? or other method that do not required any credential ?

```
public static ClientContext connectToSharepoint(string siteUrl)
{
var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
ClientContext context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl);
return context; 
}
```

[PopUp showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsHlc.png)

I tried several other method but nothing worked

** SOLVED ** added this code and it worked

```
    using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
    true))
    {
    var app = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    key.SetValue(app, 11001, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    key.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** : Added this before my code and it worked

```
    using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
    true))
    {
    var app = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    key.SetValue(app, 11001, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    key.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).